# Remove/Delete reusable token from world pay payment integration

Tags: c#, payment-gateway, worldpay

I have created order in world pay using API which return my reusable token. I am using this reusable token to do any next payment for the same order in future. I would like to delete the token now so that user can no longer use it. I have written below C# code to create order and capture the reusable token. can someone know how do i delete reusable token?

```
       WorldpayRestClient restClient = new WorldpayRestClient("https://api.worldpay.com/v1", "Key");

        var orderRequest = new OrderRequest()
        {
            token = token,
            amount = 200,
            //authorizedAmount=20,
            currencyCode = CurrencyCode.GBP.ToString(),
            name = "Laptop",
            orderDescription = "Laptop description",
            customerOrderCode = "ordercode_01",
        };

        var address = new Address()
        {
            address1 = "123 House Road",
            address2 = "A village",
            city = "London",
            countryCode = CountryCode.GB.ToString(),
            postalCode = "EC1 1AA"
        };

        orderRequest.billingAddress = address;

        try
        {
            OrderResponse orderResponse = restClient.GetOrderService().Create(orderRequest);

            string token = orderResponse.token;

            Console.WriteLine("Order code: " + orderResponse.orderCode);
        }
        catch (WorldpayException error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error code:" + error.apiError.customCode);
            Console.WriteLine("Error description: " + error.apiError.description);
            Console.WriteLine("Error message: " + error.apiError.message);
        }
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [delete-tokens](https://developer.worldpay.com/docs/wpg/tokenisation/managetokens#delete-tokens) I hope this will help you.

Comment: @Karan : I have seen that but i am not sure how do i call that in C# language.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `delete token` method is not implemented by `WorldpayRestClient` which is third party extension. Create your own `delete-token` request like below. I have taken `xxxx` just for example. Please set your actual `token` there. Also verify `url`.

You need to add `headers` as shown below. Please add `appropriate` value in it. [Check this for more detail about values](https://developer.worldpay.com/docs/access-worldpay/tokens/get-started#set-your-headers)

This is an example how you can make `DELETE` web request.

```
string token = "xxxxx";
string sURL = "https://api.worldpay.com/v1/tokens/" + token;

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(sURL);
request.Method = "DELETE";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "your_credentials");
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.worldpay.tokens-v1.hal+json");

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Comment: @Kartik Did you replace "your_credentials" with a "base64-encoded Basic Auth username and password" ?